# What is the space complexity of computing the eigenvectors of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, space-bounded, logspace

By the answer to [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14856/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-calculating-eigenvalues/14996#14996), computing the eigenvalues of a matrix to within $2^{-n}$ precision can be done in polylogarithmic space. Is it also possible to compute the eigenvectors of a matrix to within precision $2^{-n}$ in polylogarithmic space?

We can try to find the eigenvectors from the eigenvalues, but since we only have the eigenvalues up to precision $2^{-n}$, this seems to lead to a host of numerical stability issues (in particular, if there are two nearby eigenvalues, small perturbations in the matrix can lead to large perturbations in the eigenvectors).

Any references are appreciated!

Comment: I guess, analogously to the answer you are referring to, you assume a write-only, one-way tape for the output?

Comment: Yes (along with a read-only input tape and a read-write work tape of polylog(n) size).